# Black screen on nvidia laptop on ubuntu (13.10)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nomodeset

I am having a problems installing Ubuntu in my new Acer laptop. I get a black screen

I solved this problem by setting `nomodeset` following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/223798) answer before the installation. I installed Ubuntu normally.

But after I restart my laptop I have no screen.

What can I do about it ?

UPDATE: the problem seems to be my nvidia gpu, according to [this](http://linuxg.net/install-new-nvidia-drivers-nvidia-319-17-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/) article.

But should I apply these changes when I can not see my desktop

Comment: nomodeset is a kernel paramether do you have added to the new line of the kernel?

Comment: no, when i initially bootet from my usb stick, i press "down-arrow" and get advanced boot options. i set "nomodeset" there so i can install ubuntu. now it is installed, i dont use the stick anymore, but get no picture

Comment: sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Comment: then add  nomodeset to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" 
then sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

If it is your nvidia card, it should be possible to boot in recovery mode. 
Hold down left <kbd>shift</kbd> when your computer starts and the grub menu will appear.
From here you can choose recovery mode.

Comment: I bootet my usb drive again (with "nomodeset" option), I installed updates via terminal, restart, now it seems to work!

Comment: Does it really matter which shift one presses?